# Getting modules working in Joomla 3.1.4

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am experimenting with Joomla 3.1.4. Whenever I add a new module the template does not show at all in the front-end. The site is blank. On disabling the new module it starts showing properly again. Even a basic hello world type of module does not seem to work and nor does a third party extension I have tried.

I can see them in the extension manager and in the module manager and they have installed successfully. Frustrated with all this I decided to install a new 3.1 template which too installed successfully. However this template does not show anything in the front-end either with my module enabled. It almost seems that there is some sort of security restriction which is disabling the template from rendering whenever any change is made to the basic installation.

Can someone please give pointers to resolving this odd behaviour?

Comment: more than likely the module is causing a fatal error and you do not have display_errors on which would show the error on the page instead of just a blank page, check your servers error logs or turn display_errors on in your php.ini

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably one or some of the core files required for the modules to work are missing.

Head to Global configuration and make sure your Error reporting is set to development. Reload the page and update your question with the error message.

[image: Joomla settings]

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the newer Joomla 3.1.5 ([Download page](http://www.joomla.org/download.html#j3))? I know that 3.1.4 had at least one problem which could possibly cause server errors in conjunction with extensions (the most likely reason for the blank page that you see).

In general, when encountering a blank page, the first thing to do should be to check the error log of your webserver!